# Python - Sockets- Server and web browser

Tags: python, sockets

I'm playing around with sockets and I'm not really getting this on:

I have a server, on there I have my python socket server code, it works fine everything. To access and get response from the server I'm using a web browser, Firefox. 
The problem is quite simple, when my server sends me a file, I recieve it on my browser and everything's okay, but the style is quite bad cause it sends all the information and I would like to split before sending the info.

My example is, i'm sending through my server to browser /etc/shadow file, I got all the info on the browser but I'd like only to appear on the browser the username and password, that's it nothing more!

I've tried to split but I'm getting errors like, byte-object is necessary and all kind of things.

**Note: I'm using subprocess to get the /etc/shadow, but I can't with my stdout split it and only show the first two fields** [Show only the 2 fields, username and password.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d82zn.jpg)

Is there any way to split an stdout or something like that?

-Thanks in advance and sorry for my horrible English

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried formatting the information prior to sending the file?
Being able to see your code will help, as it is currently somewhat unclear where the issue lies.